# Update all fields in a Word document when user types anything

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want a way of updating all the fields on a document automatically. I currently have a macro which is linked to <kbd>F9</kbd>. This macro updates all the fields in the header and footer, as well as all the ones in the main document.

```
Sub UpdateFields()
    Dim oStory As Range
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                oStory.Fields.Update
            Wend
        End If
    Next oStory
    Set oStory = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Apart from setting the macro on every key, how would I make it so this macro runs when the user types anything?**

For example a user may place a field in the footer or header which shows the amount of characters. If this was the case I would like to be able to see the characters field update as I type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the events in Word VBA :

For the application :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn320473.aspx

For the document :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn320613.aspx

---

I would suggest that you use the `Application.WindowSelectionChange` event (Occurs when the selection changes in the active document window) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff192791.aspx

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    UpdateFields
End Sub
```

And if you need more details on that, you'll find some here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff746018.aspx